# React + urql - Invalidate all entities of a given type when using graphcache

Tags: reactjs, graphql, urql

I am using React and urql using the Graphcache and I was wondering how I would invalidate all entities of a given type after running a mutation. Checking the docs I understand that I need to setup an update but don't know what the content should be:

```
{
  // rest of the config
  updates: {
    Mutation: {
      delete_all_todos: (_result, _args, cache) => {
        cache.invalidate({ __typename: 'todo' }); // what goes here?
      },
    },
  },
}
```